# How to take selected option from select element in html and use it in js?

Tags: javascript, html

I am beginning to write code. If I wanted to have the user select an option and then have to document store which option they chose, How would I do that? For example, if I chose option 7, how would I have the document write its value? Thank you so much for your time!

```html
<p> What is your destination?
  <select>
      <option value="mercury">Mercury</option>
      <option value="venus">Venus</option>
      <option value="mars">Mars</option>
      <option value="jupiter">Jupiter</option>
      <option value="saturn">Saturn</option>
      <option value="uranus">Uranus</option>
      <option value="neptune">Neptune</option>
      <option value="pluto">Pluto</option>
  </select>
  <script type="text/javascript">
      var planets = new Array(Mercury, Venus, Mars, Jupiter, Saturn, Uranus, Neptune, Pluto);
      planets[0] = 48000000
      planets[1] = 25000000
      planets[2] = 33900000
      planets[3] = 365000000
      planets[4] = 1200000000
      planets[5] = 2600000000
      planets[6] = 2800000000
      planets[7] = 4600000000
  </script>
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Firs give the select element an id to find it by. Then you could try something like this:

```
var elm = document.getElementById('selectBox');
var selectedOption = elm.options[elm.selectedIndex].value;
```

selectedOption will contain the value that is currently selected

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps. I've added an event listener `onchange` to the select element.

```js
var planets = new Array();
planets['mercury'] = 48000000;
planets['venus']=25000000
planets['mars']=25000000
planets['jupiter']=33900000
planets['saturn']=365000000
planets['uranus']=1200000000
planets['neptune']=2600000000
planets['pluto']=2800000000

function selectDestination(selectedValue) {
  window.alert(selectedValue + " distance=" + planets[selectedValue]);
}
```

```html
What is your destination?
        <select onchange="selectDestination(this.value)">
        <option value="mercury">Mercury</option>
        <option value="venus">Venus</option>
        <option value="mars">Mars</option>
        <option value="jupiter">Jupiter</option>
        <option value="saturn">Saturn</option>
        <option value="uranus">Uranus</option>
        <option value="neptune">Neptune</option>
        <option value="pluto">Pluto</option>
        </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it is already stored in document (the select option is clicked! right?) what you seleted.

So, you don't need to store in other document the data that you selected some option.

So, let's get what option user did select!

```
$( "select option:selected" ).text();
```

if user select some option, "selected" javascript property is added to that option element. And jQuery can search element which is added "selected" property. And get text of that element.

Easy !

If you don't use jQuery, pure javascript can do same work

```
var e = document.getElementById("#idOfSelectElement");
var selectedData = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
```